# What all information is there in the federation metadata in claim based authentication?

Tags: metadata, federation

I am trying to learn about the claim based authentication and single sign on. In the meantime when we create a step of creating a trust between application and identity provider then there is a step of selecting a federation metadata.
I want to know what is the information there in the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Federation Metadata is offered by STSs to automate the trust configuration on an application. It's an unencrypted (but signed) XML document so you can open it up and look at it. At minimum you will see: the STS endpoints (e.g. used to know where to redirect to), the cryptographic information that will be used for signing the token (so it can be evaluated and verified by the application) and the claims offered (e.g. this info might not contain all that they offer).

If you are using WIF and the "Add STS reference" wizard on APS.NET for example, you can see the result of extracting this information in the web.config.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just want to know can we edit it?

Comment: Yes you can, but you have to use te API, as the doc must be signed. If you edit it manually it will be rejected because the signature will be invalid. Search for SelfSTS that (I believe) does this.